# Search user in AD without

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am creating a web application where user needs to log in using their AD credentials. On several pages, users can do another user lookup using AD. The search mechanism is as listed below. The problem is that it needs to use a valid credentials to create new Directory Entry. During development I hardcoded my credentials, thinking that each users can use their credentials by keeping the user ID and password on Session variables. However, I'm not sure whether this method is safe.

Another method I was thinking is to schedule a program to import AD records to the database but I haven't found the way to do it. Even if I found it, the program still needs to use a certain credentials, isn't?

I need some suggestions here. Below is the scripts of the lookup function. Thanks in advance.

```
        Dim enTry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(strADSvrIP, user_loginID, user_loginpassword)
        Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(enTry)


        mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(givenname=" & strKeyword & ")(name=" & strKeyword & ")(sn=" & strKeyword & ")(samAccountName=" & strKeyword & ")))"
        Dim resColl As SearchResultCollection
        Dim resEnt As SearchResult
        Dim list As New List(Of String)

        Try
            resColl = mySearcher.FindAll()

            lblResult.Text = ""

            For Each resEnt In resColl
                If Not resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("sn").Value Is Nothing Then
                    lblResult.Text = lblResult.Text & resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("samAccountName").Value.ToString() & "-"
                    lblResult.Text = lblResult.Text & resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("name").Value.ToString() & "<br>"
                End If
            Next
```

**EDIT (RESOLUTION):**

I can use the credentials from the active user by activating using ASP.NET Impersonate on the IIS  setting and use the following syntax:

```
        Dim enTry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(strADSvrIP, Nothing, Nothing, AuthenticationTypes.None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would configure your application pool to run under a domain account. This account would then be used to search AD without the need to hardcode the user name and password.

Alternatively, to search the AD under the users credentials: If you are using Windows Authentication you can call `HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Impersonate()` (or configure the application or specific pages to use automatic ASP.NET impersonation).

Comment: I am using Classic .NET AppPool. Could you share how to use the app pool and the impersonation to connect to AD? Sorry I'm pretty new in .NET.

Comment: If you use `DirectorySearcher` without specifying the username and password, the Identity you have specified for your app pool will be used to connect to AD.

Comment: I tried to change the site authentication to Windows Authentication. But when I remove the username and password from `DirectorySearcher` it didn't return anything. I'm using Classing .NET AppPool, how to set the identity?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have read the article and check the advanced setting of the app pool, it's already pointing to ApplicationPoolIdentity. But when I tried to test adding this user to some folder's ACL, I couldn't get it. Clueless here.

Comment: Don't use ApplicationPoolIdentity, use a specific domain account instead.

Comment: thank you.. I have figured out that using ASP.NET Impersonate works. I can't specify domain account as well as we don't have a specific account for this or similar purpose.